# Let-binding intermediate results in IO monad

Tags: agda, coinduction

Given this context:

```
open import IO
open import Data.String
open import Data.Unit
open import Coinduction

postulate
  A : Set
  f : String → A
  g₁ g₂ : A → String
```

let's say I want to implement something like

```
foo : IO ⊤
foo = ♯ readFiniteFile "input.txt" >>= \s →
      ♯ (♯ putStrLn (g₁ (f s)) >>
      ♯ putStrLn (g₂ (f s)))
```

by `let`-binding the intermediate result `f s`. I was hoping this would work:

```
foo₁ : IO ⊤
foo₁ = ♯ readFiniteFile "input.txt" >>= \s →
       let x = f s in
       ♯ (♯ putStrLn (g₁ x) >>
       ♯ putStrLn (g₂ x))
```

but this fails with

> Not implemented: coinductive constructor in the scope of a
>   let-bound variable

so I tried moving out the `♯`:

```
foo₂ : IO ⊤
foo₂ = ♯ readFiniteFile "input.txt" >>= \s →
       ♯ (let x = f s in
       ♯ putStrLn (g₁ x) >>
       ♯ putStrLn (g₂ x))
```

same problem as before.

I managed to get around this by just lifting out the `♯`ening step:

```
_>>′_ : ∀ {a} {A B : Set a} → IO A → IO B → IO B
m >>′ m′ = ♯ m >> ♯ m′

foo₂ : IO ⊤
foo₂ = ♯ readFiniteFile "input.txt" >>= \s →
       ♯ let x = f s in
       putStrLn (g₁ x) >>′ putStrLn (g₂ x)
```

but why does that work if the "inlined" version doesn't?

Comment: I had a quick look at projects I have involving `IO` and I ended up doing the same sort of thing. And they work alright. Ulf's [IO](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude/blob/master/src/Prelude/IO.agda) might be nicer to work with: it is a traditional monad rather than a coinductive type (but it also means that you need to assume that all the files you deal with are finite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, this problem was a long standing one and as I was having a look at it today, I noticed that [it had been fixed](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/140) just a few days before you asked your question. The fix is part of the currently released version (version 2.5.1.1).